# Почему перестают работать обработчики событий после Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

По событию происходит запрос на сервер посредством Ajax. В нескольких блоках изменяется контент, который вернул сервер. Но проблема в том, что после этого на некоторых элементах перестают работать обработчики, которые запускаются в:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ...
});
```

У меня вкладки сделаны посредством jquery и многое другое. Притом, что контент добавляется в div и обработчики на него не перестают работать. Но перестают работать обработчики, которые не повязаны с новым контентом.
Для борьбы с этой проблемой, я создал функцию, запускает все обработчики. И после возврата Ajax перезапускаю её.

Может есть какой-то более рационального решения для обхода этой проблемы?

Comment: без [mcve] ничего нельзя сказать.

Comment: запутался , можно либо другими словам описать либо код в студию

Comment: В 99% случаях проблема "перестают работать обработчики событий" связана с отсутствием делегирования. Читайте [мануалы](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Мне помогло вот это http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Век живи - век учись. Всем спасибо большое.